# ComboBox забиндить переключение на следующий элемент и на предыдущий

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Подскажите, есть ли чего-нибудь в WPF из коробки, что бы я мог забиндить сочетание клавиш при котором осуществлялось пролистывание на следующий элемент?

Или нужно реализовывать свою команду непосредственно в VM, которая будет менять текущий элемент?

Comment: В конструкторе в свойствах элементов вроде всегда было, на память не вспомнить название.

Comment: Стрелка вверх-вниз переключает на следующий-предыдущий. Но, да, можно сделать командой